# Excel VBA - Assign group marks automatically

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel table with three columns;

1. Student Name
2. Group ID
3. Group Assignment Marks

I want to write a macro to assign marks to group members automatically when I assign a mark to one group member. Can anyone please help me how to write a macro to achieve this task?

Comment: Do you want to try using Event trigger function `Worksheet_Change` Sub https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-change-event-excel#example

Comment: step 1 - write the macro : step 2 - come here and ask questions about why it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Note that write this code in appropriated Sheet module.

And revise below constants:

Sheet1: Sheet name

Table1: Table name

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'        Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim PS2 As Boolean 'sheet Protection Situation
    Dim i As Integer
    PS2 = Sheets("Sheet1").ProtectContents

    If Target.Column = [table1[Group Assignment Marks]].Column Then
        For i = 1 To ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        If Target.Row <> i + Range("Table1[#Headers]").Row Then
            If [table1].Cells(i, [table1[Student Name]].Column).Value = [table1].Cells(Target.Row - Range("Table1[#Headers]").Row, [table1[Student Name]].Column).Value Then
                [table1].Cells(i, [table1[Group Assignment Marks]].Column).Value = Target.Value

            End If
        End If
        Next i
    End If

        If PS2 Then Sheets("Sheet1").Unprotect

'    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```